# UFT + Oracle 6i Forms

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

UFT 12.5
Oracle 6i Forms(stand alone, not web)

UFT is recognizing the objects as "Window" and not as Oracle forms objects. How to solve this? Tried with only Oracle and Java add-in seperately. Read the add-in guide, but could not get any solution.

Answer (score 1):

QTP only supports Java based oracle forms with Oracle add-in. Your version of Oracle forms is very old (before Java integration). You will have to record with Windows based objects. I have automated legacy oracle forms applications with windows based objects and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check with the developers about this application. Can you please share more details on how you managed to automate with window based objects.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\Oracle\classes\mercury.properties

Change this:

1. IncludeUnnamedColumns = true
2. IgnoreOracleTableIfDeveloperNamePropertyDisabled = true